# Produce an additional column `session_age` which contains the amount of time the session is already going in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

| *timestamp* | *user_id* | *session_id* | *url* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 | 1 | 123 | https://a |
| 10:05 | 1 | 123 | https://b |
| 10:08 | 2 | 456 | https://b |
| 10:10 | 1 | 123 | https://c |

Produce an additional column `session_age` which contains the amount of time
the session is already going.

| *timestamp* | *user_id* | *session_id* | *url* | *session_age* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 | 1 | 123 | https://a | 0 |
| 10:05 | 1 | 123 | https://b | 5 |
| 10:08 | 2 | 456 | https://b | 0 |
| 10:10 | 1 | 123 | https://c | 10 |

Comment: Join the table with a subquery that gets `MIN(timestamp) ... GROUP BY session_id`, and subtract the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min()` as a window function.  Assuming the values are really full timestamps:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(second, min(timestamp) over (partition by session_id), timestamp) as diff_seconds
from t;
```